# Python installation in custom directory (Linux): PIP not working

Tags: python, linux, bash, pip

I have installed Python3.6.4 in a Linux machine, under a user directory, lets say `/drive/username/Python3.6.4`
I've setup my path and aliases, and Python is working properly (i.e. executing `python3` puts me in the correct environment, `which python3` produces: `/drive/username/Python3.6.4/bin/python3`)

The problem is with `pip`!
When i execute `pip3`, i am getting:
`-bash: /username/Python3.6.4/bin/pip3: /usr/local/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

the command `which pip3` gives: `/drive/username/Python3.6.4/bin/pip3`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my PC:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/pip3.6 
#!/usr/bin/python
...
```

So, I think your `pip` has shebang like `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6`.

Try rewrite or:

`/drive/username/Python3.6.4/bin/python3 -m ensurepip`

it will make correct `pip` in `/drive/username/Python3.6.4/bin` directory.